# How to make iReport data source connection to java classes in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ireport

I'm working with the iReport plugin for NetBeans and need to use a class for my datasource.  The documentation says you can add a link to datasources in jar files so that you can see the class fields when creating the report, by including that jar file in the iReport classpath list.  The problem is that there is no jar file with the compiled classes in NetBeans.

Does anyone know a convenient way to make a datasource connection with classes in a NetBeans project?

Or, how can I compile the java code and place that in a jar file that can be used as a datasource for iReport?

Thanks